# IE10 and showModelDialog title show #Name?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

We are in process of testing our current web application in IE10(compatibility mode). Throughout our application we use showModelDialog method and title of dialog message always end up with #Name? i.e. if title of page is My, then title appears on dialog window is My#Name?. Please use the link below to see the problem in action.
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm

Set dialog height using drop down and then click 'Push To Create' button. Dialog appears on the screen has title end with #Name?. 
In earlier versions of IE it used to be Webpage Dialog.

Is there any way to get rid of the #Name? and I do not want to use spaces after the title as there still appears ... at the end of title.

Thanks,

Comment: This is currently open as a bug with Microsoft here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/771690/modal-dialog-window-shown-in-ie-10-on-windows-8-includes-name-in-title